# How can I fix the utf8 characters problem in amp?

Tags: wordpress

In the **amp version** of my site, **Persian** language characters are displayed in an incomprehensible way.
This problem exists on one server but does not exist on another.
Do you need a special extension for it to work properly?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rm4Zy.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved.
I was using the instantify plugin. This interference occurs when the ajax option is enabled in the pwa settings.